# Make v8 object properties and methods visible to JS

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

I am wrapping a C++ object with `node::ObjectWrap` and I have some methods defined like:

```
auto tpl = NanNew<v8::FunctionTemplate>(New);
tpl->SetClassName(NanNew("className"));
tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(4);

NanSetPrototypeTemplate(tpl, NanNew("method1")  , NanNew<v8::FunctionTemplate>(Method1) , v8::ReadOnly);
NanSetPrototypeTemplate(tpl, NanNew("method2")  , NanNew<v8::FunctionTemplate>(Method2), v8::ReadOnly);
NanSetPrototypeTemplate(tpl, NanNew("method3")  , NanNew<v8::FunctionTemplate>(Method3) , v8::ReadOnly);
NanSetPrototypeTemplate(tpl, NanNew("method4")  , NanNew<v8::FunctionTemplate>(Method4), v8::ReadOnly);
```

Everything works just as expected and I can make an instance of the object in JS by:

```
var classInstance = new className();
```

All methods work just fine but when I try to log the function:

```
console.log(classInstance);
```

I am expecting to see something like:

```
{
    method1 : [Native Function],
    method2 : [Native Function],
    method3 : [Native Function],
    method4 : [Native Function]
}
```

But what I get is:

```
{}
```

Any thoughts on how to make these visible (aka enumerable)?

Comment: They are enumerable, it's just that they are on `classInstance.__proto__`, not on `classInstance` directly, and the default object serialization doesn't print the prototype chain.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Could you please make this an answer? That's what I exactly was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is essentially

```
var tpl = function(){};
tpl.prototype.method1 = function(){};
tpl.prototype.method2 = function(){};
tpl.prototype.method3 = function(){};
tpl.prototype.method4 = function(){};

var inst = new tpl();

console.log(tpl);
```

The thing is that what is printed out does not include values in the prototype chain. So `inst` doesn't actually have any properties to print, hence `{}`. Only `inst.__proto__` has properties. The properties are enumerable, so you could do `Object.keys(inst.__proto__);` to see them, but they aren't `own` properties of `inst`.